# Быстрое заполнение массива

Tags: ассемблер, sse

Почему то такая конструкция

```
vmovups [edi],ymm7
vmovups [edi+32],ymm7
```

выполняется медленнее, чем

```
movups [edi],xmm7
movups [edi+16],xmm7
movups [edi+32],xmm7
movups [edi+48],xmm7
```

Выравнивание 16 байт стоит. Такая конструкция используется в процедуре. Делаю запуск этой процедуры в цикле 8000000 итераций. Измеряю время работы цикла, вижу разницу.

адреса те же самые, единственное что меняется размерность регистра в (2 раза больше) и, соответственно, в 2 раза меньше к-во инструкций копирования.

код этого циклического вызова на Delphi

```
  TimeStart:=Now;
  For B:=0 to 8000000 do Work(@H);
    
  N:=MilliSecondsBetween(Now,TimeStart);
  S:=FormatDateTime('Прошло : ss:z', Now-TimeStart)+' - '+IntToStr(8000000000 div N);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
```

Comment: кратно ли значение [edi] 16 байтам?

Comment: В вопросе отсутствуют какие-либо намеки на измерение скорости выполнения этих конструкций. Так что что там выполняется медленнее - неизвестно, а с чего вы решили, что первая конструкция выполняется медленнее - неизвестно.

Comment: Выравнивание 16 байт стоит.

Такая конструкция используется в процедуре. Делаю запуск этой процедуры в цикле 8000000 итераций. Измеряю время работы цикла, вижу разницу.

Comment: Это все надо добавить в вопрос, чтобы читающие тоже могли увидеть разницу.

Comment: А адреса одни и те же заполняются или разные при повторных вызовах процедуры? Хорошо бы всё-таки код этого циклического вызова тоже приложить.

Comment: возможно конвейер так работает, надо unrolling попробовать